# re.findall - to extract dates from list and append it to pandas data frame

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a data set where the column "PL_email" contains nearly 650 emails, i want to extract only the first three dates out of every mail and put it in a new column. (NOTE: the dates are in different format) . so the new column should be like each cell should contain three dates if the "PL_email" cell has three or more than three dates, if it has less than three dates then it should contain the same and if one cell does not contain any dates then it should be written "No Matches"

Sample data wen converted to list:

["('can you plz email back closing stock at pool account, beneficiary account for k60022',)",
 "dear suketaben n patel (client id. s133552) kindly send it for the period 1.2.2015 to 16.07.2016',)",
 "('my client id is v888. i want p&l report for year ending 31 march 2016 for my above mentioned account.',)","('hi pls send my report for 2015-16 i.e from mar 20 2015 to jun 27 2016')"]

The above list is my "PL_email" column (i have mentioned only few for example)
Below is the code I have  tried to Extract the dates, but what is happening is it is taking out only the first date of each cell.

The code I have written is as follows:

```
df =pd.read_csv(fpath + 'PL_email.csv')
df1 = df['PL_email'].tolist()
dates = []

for element in df1:    
    m = re.findall('(\d{2,4}(/|-)\d{2,4}(/|-)\d{2,4})|(\d{2,4}(/|-)\d{2,4})|(\b\d{8}\b)|(\d{1,2}(/|-|\.)\w{3,9}(/|-|\.)\d+)|([a-z]{3,9}\s\d{2}\s\d+)|(\d{1,2}\s[a-z]{3,9}\s\d+)|(\d+(/|-|\.)\d+(/|-|\.)\d+)', element)
    for x in m:
        if x:
            print x
            dates.append(x)
            break;
    else:
        dates.append('no match')
df['dates'] = dates

df.to_csv(fpath + 'PL_email.csv', index = False)
```

Output for the code:
no match
('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1.2.2015', '', '', '')
('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '31 march 2016', '','', '', '', '', '')
('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2015-16', '', '','', '', '', '', '')

Above mentioned out is the appended out put for each cell in the CSV, 
like the first one has no matches, which is correct.
Second only has "1.2.2015".. but "16.07.2016" also has to be displayed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Try `m = re.findall(r'\d{2,4}[/-]\d{2,4}[/-]\d{2,4}|\d{2,4}[/-]\d{2,4}|\b\d{8}\b|\d{1,2}[/.-]\w{3,9}[/.-]\d+|[a-z]{3,9}\s\d{2}\s\d+|\d{1,2}\s[a-z]{3,9}\s\d+|\d+[/.-]\d+[/.-]\d+', element)`. Or even a shorter `r'\d{2,4}[/-]\d{2,4}[/-]\d{2,4}|\d{2,4}[/-]\d{2,4‌​}|\b\d{8}\b|\d{1,2}[‌​/.-]\w{3,9}[/.-]\d+|‌​[a-z]{3,9}\s\d{2}\s\‌​d+|\d{1,2}\s[a-z]{3,‌​9}\s\d+|\d+[/.-]\d+[‌​/.-]\d+'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Which can then be simplified to:

`((\d{2,4}[/-]){1,2}\d{2,4})|(\b\d{8}\b)|(\d{1,2}[/-.\s]\w{3,9}[/-.\s]\d+)|([a-z]{3,9}\s\d{2}\s\d+)|(\d+(/|-|\.)\d+(/|-|\.)\d+)`

Comment: @A.Lau: That is not that evident without any testing data. Also, `(/|-|\.)`  = `[/.-]`

Comment: I know that second part, it's just easier to understand imo, but if you're telling me that `\d{2,4}[/-]\d{2,4}[/-]\d{2,4}|\d{2,4}[/-]\d{2,4‌​}` can't be simplified, then I would like an explanation